# Fabric.js coordinates center of an object

Tags: javascript, graphics, fabricjs

```
this.graphics = new fabric.Group();
this.graphics.add(new fabric.Circle({
  left: -2.25,
  top: -2.25,
  radius: 4.5,
  fill: 'lime',
  hasBorders: false
}));
this.graphics.addWithUpdate(new fabric.Rect({
  left: 0,
  top: 0,
  width: 30,
  height: 4.5,
  fill: 'lime',
  hasBorders: false
}));
```

I'm playing around my 0,0 point, because I want to have it's coordinates every time in my future work.
Until i use addWithUpdate, and use only add - everithing is fine: i have my 0,0 point. But bound are also - zero point.
When I use addWithUpdate - my 0,0 point lost.

For example i want to use

```
this.graphics.set('left', 50);
this.graphics.set('top', 50);
```

and have NOT the top left corner of my object in 50,50, but center of my circle there( because it's my 0,0 point).

How can i do this? It's possible to specify object anchor point, or something like this?

Comment: From the documentation for Left: `Left position of an object. Note that by default it's relative to object center. You can change this by setting originX={left/center/right}` http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Rect.html#left. So set originX and originY of the object to `center`

Comment: Yep, but the problem is setting originX/Y center would point MATHEMATICAL center of group, like the center of bounding rectange. But i need my own anchor, pointing wherever i want, and for more, NOT CHANGING when i add some object to the group(if you add new object to the group - math. center moves). It's like i want to get my own coord. system for every group.

Comment: For example, first the group contain only circle - then center is in the center of the circle.
After that, adding another circle left of previous with the same  radius would move center to the circle crossing.

So i need the point, which would not move anywhere during adding.

Comment: I'm not a `fabric.js` user btw, but it seems to me that you could simply extend the `this.graphics` with some object properties that store a reference to the original X/Y origins (eg. `this.graphics.anchorPoint = { x: this.graphics.left, y: this.graphics.top }`, or a function that recalculates it and is triggered every time a new element is added..